# Bootstrap Hint JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Good day! I have Smarty template with Bootstrap, I want to connect tooltip but it doesn't work.
In header:

```
<script src="./templates/js/metro.min.js"></script>
<script src="./templates/js/metro-hint.js"></script>
```

In template:

```
<a href="#"
    data-hint="Title|This is a hint for Me"
    data-hint-position="top">
        Hover me...
</a
```

But it makes an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'split' metro-hint.js:35
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'stop' of undefined metro-hint.js:35
```

Source: [Metro UI](http://metroui.org.ua/)

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: something wrong with your metro.min.js if it can't find the split method. are you sure the file isn't corrupted?

Comment: The error is saying the split method is being called on an object. You can only call split on strings.

Comment: file isn't corrupted. google chrome

Comment: It has a dependency on jQuery. Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Yes. <script src="./templates/js/jquery.widget.min.js"></script> <script src="./templates/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script> in header

Comment: make sure that you included jquery first

Comment: all header           <link rel="stylesheet" href="./templates/css/metro-bootstrap.css">
          <script src="./templates/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script src="./templates/js/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
 <script src="./templates/js/metro.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./templates/js/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
  
       <script src="./templates/js/metro-hint.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      // pjax
      $('ul a').pjax('#main')
    })
  </script>